# I am having to use RegEx to validate several parts of a form

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, input

For this project, I have to create a pizza delivery form. There are multiple steps, and the first part is to create a form that validates the user's input. So far I have been able to partially tackle this problem. My question is 
1: Is there a more concise for validating?
2: I am trying to make it so that the submit button only appears once all the fields are validated, however, I can't figure out how to do that.
Below is my GitHub link

https://github.com/jcast90/JavaScript-RegEx-Form

```
var addressType = document.getElementById('addressType');
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var input = document.getElementById('otherInput');
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');

addressType.addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (addressType.value === 'other') {
        input.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        input.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}, false);

var state = document.getElementById('state');
var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var zip = document.getElementById('zip');
var email = document.getElementById('email');

// NAME VERIFICATION => + check if empty
name.addEventListener('focusout', focus, false);
function focus() {
    if (name.value.match(/^[a-zA-z ]*$/)) {
        name.style.border = 'solid 3px green';
        return true;
    } else {
        name.style.border = 'solid 3px red';
        name.value = '';
    }
}


// ZIP VERIFICATION => + check if empty
zip.addEventListener('focusout', zipF, false);
function zipF() {
    var zipTest = /^([0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?)/;
    if (zip.value.match(zipTest)) {
        zip.style.border = 'solid 3px green';
        return true;
    } else {
        zip.style.border = 'solid 3px red';
    }
}


// EMAIL VERIFICATION => + check if empty
email.addEventListener('focusout', emailF, false);
function emailF() {
    var emailTest = /^([a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})*$/;
    if (email.value.match(emailTest)) {
        email.style.border = 'solid 3px green';
        return true;
    } else {
        email.style.border = 'solid 3px red';
    }
}


// STATE VERIFICATION => + check if empty
var state = document.getElementById('state');
state.addEventListener('focusout', stateF, false);
function stateF() {
    var stateTest = /^(?:A[KLRZ]|C[AOT]|D[CE]|FL|GA|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEINOST]|N[CDEHJMVY |O[HKR]|PA|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AT]|W[AIVY])*$/;
    if (state.value.match(stateTest)) {
        state.style.border = 'solid 3px green';
        return true;
    } else {
        state.style.border = 'solid 3px red';
        return state.value = '';
    }
}


// PHONE VERIFICATION => add to check if empty
var phone = document.getElementById('phone');
phone.addEventListener('focusout', phoneF, false);
function phoneF() {
    var phoneTest = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    if (phone.value.match(phoneTest)) {
        phone.style.border = 'solid 3px green';
        return true;
    } else {
        phone.style.border = 'solid 3px red';
        return phone.value = '';
    }
}


function inputsTrue() {
    if (allInputs === true) {
        submit.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        submit.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}

inputsTrue();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. Regarding part 1 of your question, "better" is a matter of opinion, and it might be better to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I would recommend searching for Javascript validation libraries on Internet, also if you decide not to use any you can use jQuey to make DOM manipulation a bit easier.

Comment: @Dhyey Yeah, I've already been online to various regex pages. And I can't use jquery, only RegEx.

Comment: consider using camelCase on your variables, capitalizing variables in javascript seems awfully wrong. I properly formatted your code, it was almost unreadable without indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like this is an assignment, I've done my best to give hints instead of just giving you the answer.

1. [Input elements have a pattern attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern). You can use this to more easily check the input against a regular expression without the need for any Javascript.
2. [There is a :valid CSS pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid). You can use this to style invalid elements instead of directly applying styles in an event listener. You can also use it to style the entire form (and thus any child elements) if any input is invalid, this would be my prefered solution for hiding the submit button.

---

It may be the case that your teacher wants you to use Javascript for validation, in this case you can change a few things to make your life a bit easier.

1. You may have noticed that you have a lot of repeated code, you can pull this out into its own function that accepts the input to check, and the regex to check it against and applies the correct style depending on whether or not the regex matches. Once this is done, you can just call the function in each event listener with the correct regex and element.
2. What happens if you suddenly decide that instead of invalid inputs getting a red border, the border should be orange? Right now you would have to go back and change every function in your code. To remedy this situation, you could add and remove a class like `.valid` / `.invalid` to style the input.
3. If you use a `.valid` class, it is pretty easy to check if everything is valid. You can check if any elements with `.invalid` exist, or you can check that every one of your inputs has `.valid`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I am going to play around with it and see if I can figure it out. And I appreciate you not giving me any answers, I just needed some hints in the right direction. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for validation use jquery validation plugin.easy to use and strong validation for form.

Comment: it's for a class and we are only allowed to use RegEx for validation

Comment: http://www.webcodehelpers.com/2013/11/registration-form-validation-using-javascript-with-example.html

Comment: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml  these link help you